# Custom AJAX Login Not Registering Credentials Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

I have been working on a custom AJAX form this evening and have hit a roadblock. The modal pops up properly, I can type in my credentials. I have a popup that shows progress of submission when the submit button is clicked so I can tell that this part of the code is running properly, however it displays that my credentials are incorrect (I'm positive they are). I used this walkthrough to get started: [Tutorial](http://natko.com/wordpress-ajax-login-without-a-plugin-the-right-way/). Where could I have gone wrong? Thank you for any help!

And code!

My HTML for the modal (to be honest I wasn't sure if I needed to include "name role action and method):

```
<form class="form" name="login" id="login" role="form" action="login" method="post">
    <p class="status"></p> <!-- testing the status -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="login-name">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login-name" name="login-name" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="login-password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="login-password" name="login-password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <!-- Form Group -->
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary login-modal-button" value="Log In">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' ); ?>
</form>
```

Here is the relevant code in my functions.php:

```
function ajax_login_init(){

    wp_register_script('ajax-login-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/ajax-login-script.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-login-script');

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-login-script', 'ajax_login_object', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'redirecturl' => home_url(),
        'loadingmessage' => __('Sending user info, please wait...')
    ));

    // Enable the user with no privileges to run ajax_login() in AJAX
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', 'ajax_login' );
}

// Execute the action only if the user isn't logged in
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    add_action('init', 'ajax_login_init');
}

/* Checks the received data */

function ajax_login(){

    // First check the nonce, if it fails the function will break
    check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' );

    // Nonce is checked, get the POST data and sign user on
    $info = array();
    $info['user_login'] = $_POST['login-name'];
    $info['user_password'] = $_POST['login-password'];
    $info['remember'] = true;

    $user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user_signon) ){
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Wrong username or password.')));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=>__('Login successful, redirecting...')));
    }

    die();
}
```

Lastly, here is the JS file (included in my scripts section in footer.php):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // Perform AJAX login on form submit
    $('form#login').on('submit', function(e){
        $('form#login p.status').show().text(ajax_login_object.loadingmessage);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: ajax_login_object.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                'action': 'ajaxlogin', //calls wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin
                'username': $('form#login #login-name').val(),
                'password': $('form#login #login-password').val(),
                'security': $('form#login #security').val() },
            success: function(data){
                $('form#login p.status').text(data.message);
                if (data.loggedin == true){
                    document.location.href = ajax_login_object.redirecturl;
                }
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Comment: `'action': 'ajaxlogin', //calls wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin` - how does this happen?

Comment: what error message is showing up in the console?

Comment: are there any errors in the httpd error log?

Comment: `add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', 'ajax_login' );` suggests it should be `'action': 'ajax_login'` - but my PHP is rusty

Comment: @JaromandaX changing to `'action': 'ajax_login'` just makes the modal get stuck at the string: "Sending user info, please wait..."

Comment: @mike510a there is an error in console related to modal, this is what it says: "Uncaught TypeError: b(...).modalmanager is not a function" it pops up when I click the button to open the modal

Comment: theres your problem

Comment: Sorry for my "noise" ... as I said, PHP is rusty :p

Comment: @mike510a ok so interesting issue. Looks like this is because bootstrap is defined before jquery? However, by switching the lines, the dropdown menu navbar will not go back up now.

Comment: @mike510a also, it should be mentioned that removing the console error did not fix the login issue

Comment: @JordanLewallen, It is fixed?

Comment: @vel no, still stuck here!

Comment: Ajax login not working in popup. Right?

Comment: @vel correct! It shows the status of "sending user info please wait" but fails to confirm the accurate credentials. Also, might have to do with that I have the bootstrap js above the jquery js? But this is the only way I can get both the modal and the mobile menu to function properly...strange

Comment: ok. Let me check.

Comment: Its is custom login page?. user and admin can login here or users only?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131275/discussion-between-jordan-lewallen-and-vel).

Comment: @JordanLewallen, ANswer updated and check the chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
        <?php
        /*
         * Template Name: login check
         */

        get_header();

        ?>

        <form class="form" name="login" id="login" role="form" action="login" method="post">
            <p class="status"></p> <!-- testing the status -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="login-name">Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login-name" name="login-name" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="login-password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="login-password" name="login-password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <!-- Form Group -->
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary login-modal-button" value="Log In">
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' ); ?>
        </form>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            // Perform AJAX login on form submit
            $('form#login').on('submit', function(e){
                $('form#login p.status').show().text('Sending user info, please wait...');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );?>",
                    data: {
                        action: 'ajax_login', //calls wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin
                        'username': $('form#login #login-name').val(),
                        'password': $('form#login #login-password').val(),
                        'security': $('form#login #security').val() },

                    success: function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                        $('form#login p.status').text(data.message);
                        if (data.loggedin == true){
                            //document.location.href = ajax_login_object.redirecturl;
                        }
                    },error: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }

                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });

        });
        </script>

        <?php
        get_footer();
```

add below code in functions.php

```
function ajax_login_init(){

wp_register_script('ajax-login-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/ajax-login-script.js', array('jquery') );
wp_enqueue_script('ajax-login-script');

wp_localize_script( 'ajax-login-script', 'ajax_login_object', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'redirecturl' => home_url(),
    'loadingmessage' => __('Sending user info, please wait...')
));

// Enable the user with no privileges to run ajax_login() in AJAX

}
add_action('init', 'ajax_login_init');
```

/* Checks the received data */

```
function ajax_login(){

// First check the nonce, if it fails the function will break
check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' );

// Nonce is checked, get the POST data and sign user on
$info = array();
$info['user_login'] = $_POST['login-name'];
$info['user_password'] = $_POST['login-password'];
$info['remember'] = true;

$user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );
if ( is_wp_error($user_signon) ){
    echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Wrong username or password.')));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=>__('Login successful, redirecting...')));
}

die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_login', 'ajax_login' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_login', 'ajax_login' );
```

**updated**

Seems you trying to login with username. so login not working. If you want to login with email and username you need to add below function.

```
 function login_with_email_address($user, $username, $password) {
    if (is_email($username))
    {
        $user = get_user_by('email', $username);
        if($user)
            $username = $user->user_login;
    }
    return wp_authenticate_username_password(null, $username, $password);
}


 add_filter('authenticate', 'login_with_email_address', 20, 3);
```

Comment: This works flawlessly! Also, to note, if you would like the webpage to re-direct, uncomment the `document.location.href = ajax_login_object.redirecturl;` Thank you :)